# Bet with coin, empty glass bottle and cork

Tags: coins

> You have a coin, an empty glass bottle and a cork. If you throw the coin into the bottle and close up the bottle with the cork, how can you pull out the coin, without pulling out the cork or smashing the bottle?

Comment: Nice puzzle, Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I edited your question a bit to make it more clear. You should [take the tour](/tour) for an easy badge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

> push the cork into the bottle and then shake out the coin afterwards.

Comment: Good!Just have to wait 13 mins...

Comment: It's not clear to me why that should count as "without removing the cork".

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I think it the problem is usually phrased as "without removing the cork from the bottle", and this certainly isn't doing that.

Comment: The original riddle (before the edit) had stated "without pulling out the cork" I think; let me revise that!